# Hot water not always hot

Tags: plumbing

I moved into a flat in January and for a couple of months we've had issues with the hot water not always being hot. It's a combi boiler, no idea how old it is. Sometimes it's luke warm and then goes cold, sometimes stone cold and sometimes boiling hot. We use it at the same time different days with different results. 
It's a rental property and the letting agents has sent a plumber twice and he's always got hot water and has said there's no issue. Hes not very friendly so I'm not sure if he's investigated or assuming its fine because it works for him. I don't want to keep bothering the letting agents but surely there has to be something wrong with the boiler.

Comment: Was it perfectly OK in January and February? Did it get as much use then as it has recently? How long do you run the hot water for when it starts cold? Can you see if the boiler comes on soon after you turn on a hot tap? Do you know the make and model of boiler? Are there zone valves for the hot water? Is the heating (radiators?) OK? Photos?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the issue is with the 3-way valve. Try closing all the radiators valves (one by one, not just the thermostat) then have a shower, if temperature doesn't fluctuate (much), 3 way is the first suspect.
Another cause can be the frequent open/close of taps: because the boiler starts few seconds after water is turned on so there's a bit of cold water coming through the hot water pipes, to avoid this problem just keep hot water open when you're using it. The second problem, on some models, can be solved by boilers' function that keeps the secondary heat exchanger always hot.